# Apache POI: Is it possible to use SXSSF without temporary files?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'd like to use `SXSSF` (Streaming Usermodel API) from **Apache POI**.
What I don't like is that it uses temporary files.

**Question:**
Is it possible in Apache POI to flush directly to the output stream **without the use of temporary files**?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Axel : I need to create a download servlet to enable very large excel file downloads. Ideally, the download servlet should not need to store any temporary files due to various reasons (security, disk space, cluster etc.)

Comment: @MRalwasser, you can delete temp files with calling SXSSFWorkbook.dispose();.

Answer (score 4):

No

In order to generate a valid Excel `.xlsx` file, there are various bits of the file which need to agree with each other. These references, links, ids etc need to be updated by Apache POI when writing the file out

You therefore have two options:

- XSSF - No temporary files, everything very easy to work with, everything kept in memory
- SXSSF - Various restrictions, large parts streamed into temporary files, small bits in memory

If you don't want temp files, buy some more memory and use XSSF!

Also, don't forget that you can control where POI places the temporary files, if the default doesn't work well for you

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can stop the temp file generation during excel file generation. Either you have to zip the temp file or dispose the temp file. But dispose is recommended as the file will not be created again if you call the dispose method.

Code Snippet

```
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new 
SXSSFWorkbook(100);

// write your code.

wb.dispose();  
// This method will help to stop the temp file generation.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also compress the file

```
wb.setCompressTempFiles(true);
```

It will make a zip file of the temp file. But dispose is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

POI 5.2.+ has DeferredSXSSFWorkbook which uses fewer temp files. See https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/streaming/DeferredGeneration.java

Comment: "fewer temp files" are not no "temp files". And btw, DeferredSXSSFWorkbook is still somewhat "experimental" - see https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@poi.apache.org/msg34019.html
EDIT: Just realized that you're are the author of the message I am refering to - therefore you're aware of this ;)